# Generate Wishart Distribution using rWishart within Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to get R's rWishart in stats to work within Rcpp. Here is a test example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rWishart_cpp(int p, int df, NumericMatrix Sigma) {
    return rWishart(p, df, Sigma);
}
```

The error I receive is:
"test.cpp:12:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rWishart'
    return rWishart(p, df, Sigma);"

From one of the vignettes, I thought d/r functions were implemented in Rcpp courtesy of Rmath.h?

In any case, is there any way I can generate a wishart distribution within Rcpp?

Comment: Per @dirk's suggestion, I recently wrote a port of the wishart function to armadillo.

It is available here: https://github.com/coatless/r-to-armadillo/blob/master/wishart_dist.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you assume Wishart is in `Rmath.h` when it isn't:

```
edd@max:~$ grep -i wish /usr/include/Rmath.h         # no Wishart
edd@max:~$ grep -i weib /usr/include/Rmath.h         # but Weibull has an example
#define dweibull        Rf_dweibull
#define pweibull        Rf_pweibull
#define qweibull        Rf_qweibull
#define rweibull        Rf_rweibull
        /* Weibull Distribution */
double  dweibull(double, double, double, int);
double  pweibull(double, double, double, int, int);
double  qweibull(double, double, double, int, int);
double  rweibull(double, double);
edd@max:~$
```

The best bet would be to get another implementation from somewhere and code that up via Rcpp.

*Edit:*
Or based on two minutes worth of research at [rdocumentation.org](http://www.rdocumentation.org), you can probably follow the documentation of `stats::rWishart` and code this up as a function for multivariate Normals. I'd based this on
RcppArmadillo....

Comment: Or, even more efficiently, using the Bartlett decomposition for the Wishart (see Wiki page for the Wishart).